# On MacOS, how can I include the Octave graphics toolkit from octave-cli on Octave 5.1?

Tags: plot, command-line-interface, octave

Under MacOS (Sierra 10.13.6 if that matters), I have some Octave scripts developed which work well under the Octave-gui, but won't run from the octave-cli. They include graphics to plot results; how can one include the required graphics toolkits when Octave is launched from the cli?

I have tried other hints and tips including enhancing the path and adding an alias to octave-cli, which makes it simpler to launch octave-cli from a script, but still get:

```
GNU Octave, version 5.1.0
Copyright (C) 2019 John W. Eaton and others.
...
octave:1> gt_7tCurrieLiFe1 
Time to read the dataset:  0.48 sec 
Time to parse the dataset: 0.0013 sec 
Time for loop over the dataset: 18.47 sec 
error: no graphics toolkits are available!
error: called from
    figure at line 91 column 7
    gt_7tCurrieLiFe1 at line 61 column 1
...
[line 61 of gt_7tCurrieLiFe1.m]
plot(1:endcount, gt_data(:,3), "linestyle", "-", ...
     1:endcount, gt_data(:,4), "linestyle", "--")
...
```

What I expected was the plot window to open as it does when the same script is run from the Octave GUI.

Thanks for any tips to get further on this task.

Comment: Have you tried `octave-gui --no-gui` ?

Comment: This should work under most scenarios. It sounds like maybe your CLI version of Octave was built without graphics support? How did you install your GUI and CLI Octaves, and what command line are you using to call them?

Comment: Ping? This still broken for you?